# CodeIgniter - multiple instances of a model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIginter as my PHP framework. I am explaining the situation below: -

I need three models named: -

- User_Model
- Relation_Model
- Reminder_Model

Now consider the situation:

`User_Model` is already written. I am writing `Relation_Model`. My friend will write the `Reminder_Model`.

`Relation_Model` instantiates `User_Model`, and uses that, in one of its method: `getRelation($userID)`

`Reminder_Model` also instantiates one `User_Model` instance for its functioning.

`Reminder_Model` needs to call `getRelation` method of Relation_Model.

So, there should be at least two instances of `User_Model`. One in `Relation_Model`, another in `Reminder_Model`.

The problem is how do I ensure **inside** `Relation_Model`, that my `User_Model` instance does not interfere with the `User_Model` instance of my friend’s `Reminder_Model` class?

That is, to code `Reminder_Model`, my friend should not have internal knowledge of `Relation_Model`, just to use one of its method `getRelation`.

If you want to know the need for this, say: Reminder_Model loads the model of the user who has logged in (say user-A), Relation_Model works with the models of the users who are member of user-A's team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you can't use the same instance of the User_Model class, but maybe loading the model twice, once with plain old **$this->load->model('User_Model')** and second with **$this->load->model('Use_Model', 'Second_User_Model')** will help. Or you could [clone](http://www.php.net/language.oop5.cloning) the object like **$this->second_user_model = clone $this->user_model**.

Comment: The first method, will require, the implementer of Reminder_Model to have internal knowledge of Relation_Model (the fact that inside Relation_Model, I have instantiated User_Model with the name of Second_User_Model!).
Yes, I also finally thought of cloning.